# What parts of an animal require kashering prior to eating?

Tags: halacha, meat, parts-of-the-body, kashering-kosherization

I assume that the reason for koshering meat is to get rid of the blood.

If that is the case, if someone eats gribenes, which are fried chicken skins,  do the skins need to be koshered? What if one were able to carefully peel away the raw skin from the rest of the meat assuring that there was no blood in it?

For that matter, if one were to eat sheep's wool, rooster combs or chicken feathers, would any of these require koshering, if there is no blood in them?

Comment: I don't know what rooster combs are (and yes, I could probably figure it out with a quick Google, but that's besides the point) but wool and feathers I don't believe are considered food. You can't classify them as kosher/nonkosher/meat/dairy/etc. just like you can't classify a shoe as meat/dairy/etc.

Comment: Pretty sure you answered your own question

Comment: @Salmononius2 rooster combs are the red comb-like structure on he rooster's head. It is used commonly in certain pills and medicine for, I believe, arthritis. I'm uncertain if it is used otherwise for non-medicinal use. Chicken feathers, BTW, are eaten, although, most of the time "accidentally" such as when consumers don't care to bother cleaning the chicken legs sufficiently. Nonetheless, that would qualify it as edible.

Comment: @DanF "Edible" does not equal "food". Paper is edible, but you don't make a bracha on it, it isn't pareve, etc. I have seen people eat light bulbs, that too isn't considered food just because someone happened to eat it.

Comment: Liver, if broiled, doesn't need kashering.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I LOVE that ID!!! Re liver, the broiling process is the kashering. For livers, salting alone doesn't do the job. In my question, I;m asking about doing nothing at all and just eating these items.

Comment: Unlaid chicken eggs? http://www.fieldandfeast.com/guest-bio/the-chicken-and-the-unlaid-eggs/